# Plotly bar graph is plotting a two combined columns instead of the defined one

Tags: python, plotly, stock

I am using plotly to make a combined candlestick and bar graph. The candle stick works great but when I attempt to use my volume column for a graph it grabs another value with it and breaks the value.

[Result that has the time in front of the volume so it comes out formatted like (10:30, 100,000)]

[image]

Here is the code

[image]

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=newdb['Time'],
    open=newdb['Open'],
    high=newdb['High'],
    low=newdb['Low'],
    close=newdb['Close']),
    secondary_y=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=newdb['Time'], y=newdb['Volume']))

fig.update_layout(
    title=symbol + entrytime
)

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename=savepath)
```

Here is the database being used to build the charts

[image]

|  | Time | Open | Close | High | Low | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 09:30 | 5.59 | 5.39 | 5.59 | 5.35 | 400,367.00 |
| 1 | 09:31 | 5.40 | 5.30 | 5.45 | 5.30 | 209,372.00 |
| 2 | 09:32 | 5.39 | 5.23 | 5.45 | 5.23 | 263,697.00 |
| 3 | 09:33 | 5.32 | 5.29 | 5.36 | 5.23 | 266,023.00 |
| 4 | 09:34 | 5.24 | 5.37 | 5.37 | 5.23 | 221,823.00 |

I expected this code to work since the candlesticks work the same way. I also tried changing the defined index of the dataframe to time instead of the normal index to see if that would help and it did not. I tried converting it to a string or integer which it did not let me.

Comment: don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the data type was not numerical so I added this to resolve it.

```
fig.update_layout(autotypenumbers='convert types')
```